# Ubuntu program won't start as a service

Tags: 14.04, server, services, autostart

Quite a newbie to Linux and servers.
I have a program I like to start on boot.

Executing the program in its folder works fine.
Trying to execute the program from outside of the installation folder produces a couple of errors like config file not found, language folder not found and so on.

```
22:06:24> Error: there was an error loading languages. Please check your language folder.
22:06:24> Loading configuration.
22:06:24> ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'config.default.json'
22:06:24> Error: config.default.json is broken or missing. Shutting down.
```

I like to use something like

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/home/xxx/yyy/zzz/startkmr1
```

but it doesn't work.

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/home/xxx/yyy/zzz/./startkmr1
```

doesn't work either.

I like to run the program as a service from boot.

If I'm in the directory of startkmr1 and execute `./startkmr1`, it works.
Any help very appreciated.

Comment: Services usually run as a different user than you, so it might look for configuration files in a different location. Check the documentation for that program to find out where it looks for configuration files.

Comment: For me it seems, it's not the service which is looking in other directories, the same happens if I use ssh as the same user:group as the executable file, only one directory above said file.

Comment: By "service" I mean your `startkmr1` executable. If it is only looking in the current working directory then it is really badly designed, but then you can work around it by first changing to that directory.

Comment: Try adding a `WorkingDirectory=/home/xxx/yyy/zzz/` line to the service file.

Answer (score 0):

When you have an executable which looks in the working directory for configuration, data or library files, and you want to run it as a service, you can set the working directory in the service file with the `WorkingDirectory` directive.

You can find information about this and other directives in the [`systemd.service` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man5/systemd.service.5.html).